# How can I set max length of Hashids?

Tags: hash, hashids

I use `Hashids`(http://hashids.org/python/) in my `Django` project.

I want to create hash with fixed length.

But `Hashids` supports only `min_length`:

```
hash_id = Hashids(
    salt=os.environ.get("SALT"),
    min_length=10,
)
```

How can I set fixed length(say, 10 characters) of `hash_id`?

Answer (score 5):

While I haven't used the python version of the library, I still feel that I can answer since I'm maintaining the .NET version and they mostly share the same algoritm.

Just thinking of this logically, fixing the length of the hash (or setting a max-length) in combination with allowing the user to define alphabet and salt, limits the possible variations of the hash and therefor also limiting which numbers that can be encoded.

I am guessing that's why it isn't possible with the library today.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set the **min_length** of a hashid but it gets trickier setting the **max_length** as this would require setting a **minimum length** on the integer passed. Please avoid doing so in production environments as this could impact your system negatively. The sample code below indicates how to set **min_length** for **PHP Laravel** if using a different language kindly check for hashid implementation based on the language you are using.

```
namespace App\Hashing;

use Hashids\Hashids;

    class Hash {
        private $salt_key;
        private $min_length;
        private $hashid;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->salt_key = '5OtYLj/PtkLOpQewWdEj+jklT+oMjlJY7=';
            $this->min_length = 15;
            $this->hashid = new Hashids($this->salt_key, $this->min_length);
        }

        public function encodeId($id){
            $hashed_id = $this->hashid->encode($id);
            return $hashed_id;
        }

        public function decodeId($hashed_id){
            $id = $this->hashid->decode($hashed_id);
            return $id;
        }
    }

    $hash = new Hash();
    $hashed_id = $hash->encodeId(1);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($hashed_id);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo "<pre>";
    $id = $hash->decodeId($hashed_id);
    print_r($id[0]);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set "min_length" in Hashids

for example:

```
hashids = Hashids(min_length=16, salt="my salt")
hashid = hashids.encode(1) # '4q2VolejRejNmGQB'
```

for more details click [here](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python)